# Launch service when app goes in background

Tags: android, android-service

I have an app with some activities, and a service that should be launch when entire app goes into background. 
Now i launch service when my main activity call onStop method, but this method is called also when i start a new activity of my app (and in this case, service shouldn't be started).
there's a way to check when my app (not a specific activity) goes into background, or i need to check it for each activity?

Comment: *and in this case, service shouldn't be started* ...wrong ... you should start service .... service should do all the work ... activity should only display the UI (Bind service and use it) ... my assumption is that you have almost the same code in the activity and in the service and you wana start the service to "something" continue to working ...

Comment: I shouldn't start service if my app isn't in background. If my app is in foreground, i've already an asynctasks that do the job. When app goes into background, i need to start service that, if some conditions is verified, show a notification into status bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isApplicationBroughtToBackground() {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

for more information [see this](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to create a Application level class for this and will set boolean value for every screen i am showing you how to do in single screen or activity....

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static boolean mainActivityVisible;

public static boolean isMainActivityVisible() {
    return mainActivityVisible;
}  

public static void mainActivityResumed() {
    mainActivityVisible = true;
}

public static void mainActivityPaused() {
    mainActivityVisible = false;
}
```

}

Then in MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    MyApplication.mainActivityPaused();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.mainActivityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
  if(isAppRunning(context))
    {
        if(MyApplication.isMainActivityVisible())
        {
           //Means activity not in background so dont start service or broadcasting
        }
        else
        {
          //Means activity is in background so start service here..
         } 
    }
    else
    {
       //Means app is not alive...so start also service here
    }
}
```

Method isAppRunning here

```
public static boolean isAppRunning(Context context) {
    // check with the first task(task in the foreground)
    // in the returned list of tasks
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager
.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    if (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().toString()
.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName().toString())) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```